# Get simple variable from php file (NSURL)

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to get the version name from a php file for my iphone app.

```
//version.php
 <?php 
    echo '1.0'; 
 ?>
```

How can I get the "1.0" into a NSString?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
<?php 

   echo json_encode(array('version' =>'1.0'));

?>
```

you retreive json string and (json)decode it, get the array.
this link to halp you : http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/